# Can a consistent theory prove its inconsistency?

Tags: lo.logic

Suppose PA is consistent. Godel's theorem says that it cannot prove its own consistency.
So, could there be a proof in PA that PA is inconsistent ?
That wouldn't lead to a direct contradiction, so could that situation actually happen ?

Then what ? The theory would be lying to us even though it is consistent. How do we know it's not lying about other stuff ?

Comment: Re your final question, if you believe the axioms of PA are true, then it can't lie to us because its rules of inference are truth-preserving.  If you believe that not all the axioms of PA are true, then of course it *is* lying to us.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg The last clause in your comment should probably read "then of course you believe that it *is* lying to us."

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  Yes, I completely accept your correction.  The same correction applies to my first sentence as well.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question in the title: Yes, there are consistent theories that prove their own inconsistency. One example is the theory obtained from PA by adding the axiom "PA is inconsistent." This is consistent, by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, and it proves its own inconsistency because it proves the inconsistency of the (provably) weaker theory PA.

On the other hand, PA itself is not an example for the title question, because all its axioms are true of the standard natural numbers, logical deduction preserves truth, and "PA is inconsistent" isn't true.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my mind around what you wrote.  If I were to assert that a theory proved its own inconsistency I would mean "There exists a statement P for which the system proves P, and it also proves ~P."  This is clearly impossible for an actual consistent system.  By "proving its own inconsistency" are you only asserting that there is a provable statement Q which can merely be *interpreted* as asserting the system is inconsistent?

Comment: @PaceNielsen To say that a theory $T$ proves its own consistency means that $\neg\text{Con}(T)$ is a theorem of $T$, where $\text{Con}(T)$ is the usual formalization of consistency of $T$, exactly as in the statement of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm a bit surprised by that answer, since "the usual formalization" seems to me to be non-canonical.  For instance, using a different Gödel numbering, couldn't you come up with a different sentence (newly interpreted as ${\rm Con}(T)$), but which now is once again independent?  Or is it the case that whether or not a theory proves it own consistency (or inconsistency) is *independent* of which Gödel numbering you use?

Comment: @PaceNielsen Switching to a different Gödel numbering won't matter, as long as the basic syntactic operations are definable and provably work as they should. But switching to a different definition of "axiom of PA" can matter. If I define "good-axiom of PA" to mean an axiom $A$ of PA (in the usual sense) such that $A$ and all axioms of PA with smaller Gödel numbers than $A$ are jointly consistent, and if I then define consistency of PA in terms of the good-axioms, PA will prove its own consistency in this new sense, even though in fact the good-axioms are exactly the axioms of PA. [continued]

Comment: [continuation of previous comment] For Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, one needs a well-behaved formulation of provability. Technically, that means the Hilbert-Bernays derivability conditions (though maybe something weaker could work). For lots of information about such things, see Solomon Feferman's paper "Arithmetization of metamathematics in a general setting" (http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm49/fm4915.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for that link!  As I suspected, Feferman shows that "consistency" is an intensional concept.  By the way, he seems to disprove your claim that PA cannot prove its own inconsistency.  See Theorem 6.6 and the paragraph that follows, where he shows that if PA is consistent then it contains a non-standard model which models PA + ~Con(PA).  By the way, since consistency is intensional, your proof above that "PA+ ~Con(PA)" proves it own inconsistency has a hole.  You still need to prove that the  statement "~Con(PA)" can be interpreted correctly in the now stronger theory.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I don't understand most of your comment. First, the fact that "if PA is consistent then it contains a nonstandard model which models PA + ~Con(PA)" is just saying that, if PA is consistent then it doesn't prove Con(PA), i.e., the second incompleteness theorem. (I assume "contains" is intended to mean "has"; in the usual terminology, theories don't contain models.) Second, I don't see where you see a hole in the proof that PA + ~Con(PA) proves its own inconsistency; in particular, how is "interpreting it in the new stronger theory" relevant? [continued in next comment]

Comment: [continuation of preceding comment] With the usual formulations of consistency statements, it is easy to prove in PA (in fact, to prove finitistically) that, for any sentence S, Con(PA + S) implies Con(PA). Taking S to be ~Con(PA), and taking the contrapositive, we get that ~Con(PA) provably implies ~Con(PA+ ~Con(PA)).

Comment: I'll address your second question first.  You asserted "a theory $T$ proves its own consistency means that $\neg{\rm Con}(T)$ is a theorem of $T$".  This is actually impossible for any consistent (sufficiently strong) theory, by the second incompleteness theorem.  Thus, for instance, when $T={\rm PA}+\neg{\rm Con}({\rm PA})$, it does prove the syntactic sentence $\neg{\rm Con}_{\rm PA}({\rm PA})$, but it does **not** prove the syntactic sentence $\neg{\rm Con}_T(T)$.  Your argument that the consistency of ${\rm PA}$ is *provably* weaker than the consistency of ${\rm T}$ is not in $T$.

Comment: In other words, $\neg{\rm Con}(T)$ is not a theorem of $T$.  Even though you are correct (meta-mathematically) that the inconsistency of ${\rm PA}$ implies the inconsistency of $T$, that does not mean that $\neg{\rm Con}_{\rm PA}({\rm PA})\implies \neg{\rm Con}_T(T)$ in $T$.

Comment: Regarding your first question, what I said does in fact go beyond the second incompleteness theorem.  It relates to interpretability: we can interpret/model $T$ *within* ${\rm PA}$.  So for instance, there is no non-standard model within ${\rm PA}$ which models ${\rm PA}+{\rm Con}({\rm PA})$ by Theorem 6.5; but there is such a non-standard model for ${\rm PA}+{\rm Con}({\rm PA})$ by Theorem 6.6.  See the paragraph that follows Theorem 6.6 for more details.  The footnote (21) is perhaps related to your question.

Comment: @PaceNielsen The first two of  your last 3 comments are wrong (or perhaps meaningless, since you use the notation $\text{Con}_X(X)$ for various theories $X$ without saying what it is supposed to mean or how it's supposed to differ from the customary $\text{Con}(X)$). The second incompleteness theorem says that a consistent sufficiently strong theory can't prove its own **consistency** (when the consistency is formulated in a natural way, satisfying the derivability conditions); it does not prevent such a theory from proving its own **inconsistency**. [continued in nest comment]

Comment: [continuation] Also, the implication from $\neg\text{Con}(PA)$ to $\neg\text{Con}(PA+S)$  is provable in PA (and in far weaker theories), for any sentence $S$. (To avoid weird formalizations, whatever formula $A(x)$ is used to formalize "$x$ is an axiom of PA", one should use "$A(x)\lor x=\bar s$ to formalize "$x$ is an axiom of PA + S", where $s$ is the Gödel number of $S$ and $\bar s$ is the numeral for $s$.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen Your third comment has a typo, a missing negation, but what you intended to cite from Feferman is correct (except that Feferman seems to carefully put "model" in quotation marks when he means interpretation rather than an actual model). PA + $\neg$Con(PA) is interpretable in PA, and PA + Con(PA) is not interpretable in PA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49993/discussion-between-pace-nielsen-and-andreas-blass).